# Customize maven build

Tags: maven, customization, http-unit

Is that possible to customize a maven build lifecycle without writing a plugin? I want to customize my project to package it without running tests, then run the tests. The background is that the tests are running on HTTPUnit and it needs a fully constructed web application directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by khmarbaise you can use [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) which is an extension of maven-surefire-plugin.

Maven lifecycle has four phases perfect for your intent:

1. `pre-integration-test` for setting up the integration test
   environment.
2. `integration-test` for running the integration tests.
3. `post-integration-test` for tearing down the integration test
   environment.
4. `verify` for checking the results of the integration
   tests.

generally speaking during the `pre-integration-test` [we start the server](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html)

eg:

```
   <executions>
      [...]
      <execution>
        <id>start-jetty</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run-exploded</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop-jetty</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
```

I use this plugin with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/); in [Maven Build Customization - Chapter 5](http://bit.ly/10kN5MT)  you can find further details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are writing integration tests.

You could use [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/). This plugin is executed by default at the integration-test phase of the [maven build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) (which is after the packaging phase)...

Answer (score 1):

For those purposes you need the integration-test phase which exactly is intended for such things. It's after the packaging phase but before install/deploy phase.
This can be achieved by using the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/). You can find a full example [here](http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/it-example-container.html).